# How to register multiple servlets in web.xml in one Spring application

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web.xml

I want to define two servlets in my Spring web.xml - one for the application html/jsp pages, and one for a web service that will be called by an external application.  Here is the web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/user-service-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>user-webservice</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>user-webservice</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/UserService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I have myservlet use the DispatcherServlet in the file by itself, it works fine.  If I have the user-webservice with the context-param for it's config file (user-service-servlet.xml), it works fine.  However, if I have both in the file, then the myservlet doesn't work as the myservlet-servlet.xml file isn't loaded automatically.  If I remove the context-param, then the myservlet works, but the user-webservice doesn't work as it's configuration file (user-service-servlet.xml) isn't loaded.

How can I have both servlets defined and both of their configuration files loaded?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As explained in [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/JAX-WS---multiple-services-in-separate-jars-td18336903.html) on the cxf-user mailing list, rather than having the CXFServlet load its own spring context from `user-webservice-servlet.xml`, you can just load the whole lot into the root context. Rename your existing `user-webservice-servlet.xml` to some other name (e.g. `user-webservice-beans.xml`) then change your `contextConfigLocation` parameter to something like:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    /WEB-INF/user-webservice-beans.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>user-webservice</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>user-webservice</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/UserService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How can context for both servlets can be in root context, if separate databases and other settings are used? How are they distinguished between in one file?

Answer (score 6):

Use config something like this:

```xml
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>user-webservice</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and then you'll need three files:

- applicationContext.xml;
- myservlet-servlet.xml; and
- user-webservice-servlet.xml.

The `*-servlet.xml` files are used automatically and each creates an application context for that servlet.

From the Spring documentation, [13.2. The DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-servlet):

> The framework will, on initialization
>   of a `DispatcherServlet`, *look for a
>   file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml*
>   in the `WEB-INF` directory of your web
>   application and create the beans
>   defined there (overriding the
>   definitions of any beans defined with
>   the same name in the global scope).

Comment: This doesn't help - I have those files in my application, but when I go to http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.jsp, it shows the page, but when I go to http://localhost:8080/MyApp (with no trailing slash), it brings up the user-webservice, but clicking on the WSDL link shows the "No services have been found" message.  Perhaps my problem is no that the config files aren't being loaded, but the mapping to the web service is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but the answer in short would be <load-on-startup> both occurrences have given the same id which is 1 twice. This may confuse loading sequence.