# Spring MVC multiple servlets (Jersey,Dispatcher) problem

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

I have one DispatcherServlet for my pages, and one ServletContainer for my Jersey webservice. **As it is now, no pages are rendering (404), but the service is working fine. How can I run them in conjunction?**

I saw this thread [How to register multiple servlets in web.xml in one Spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865088/how-to-register-multiple-servlets-in-web-xml-in-one-spring-application) that seems to deal with a similar issue, though that was regarding CXF so I'm unsure how relevant it is.

I also tried having a separate Jersey-servlet.xml file, but that made both the pages and the service stop working. Don't really know where to go from this point, any help much appreciated.

web.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>HSRMVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HSR</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HSR</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>se.hsr.services</param-name>
      <param-value>HSRMVC</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HSR-sevlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="se.hsr.web"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

UPDATED web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>HSRMVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HSR</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HSR</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
    /resources/applicationContext.xml
    /WEB-INF/service-beans.xml
  </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>service-beans</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>se.hsr.services</param-name>
            <param-value>HSRMVC</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>service-beans</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: "no pages are rendering (404), but the service is working fine"... what does that mean?

Comment: That means that when I point to say localhost/login.hmtl, I get a 404 -error. When I write localhost/service/emil , I get a page displaying my name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem.

This is how my new web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>HSRMVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/HSR-service-beans.xml
  </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HSR</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HSR</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HSR-service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>se.hsr.services</param-name>
            <param-value>HSRMVC</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HSR-service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How does `<param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml` work? What are the names of context config files for your servlets? `<context-param>` provides location for parent context, which is one for all servlets - or isn't?

Comment: Hi Mikhail. Sorry, but since this was five years ago, I barely have any recollection of this at all to be honest. Hope someone else is able to answer this!

Answer (score 3):

[The question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865088/how-to-register-multiple-servlets-in-web-xml-in-one-spring-application) is relevant to your scenario.

You can also try using [`<mvc-default-servlet-handler />`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler). It is not meant exactly for this purpose, though. (it's meant for static resources).

Also check [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/jersey_and_spring) and [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/09/14/integrating-jersey-and-spring).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read the resources you linked to but still don't quite understand how to make it work. I tried editing my web.xml (see originalpost), but the problem persists identically to before.