# Multiple servlets with different context in one Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a Spring application, which has to have two servlets (`dispatcherMain` and `dispatcherCatalog`) working with different databases via Hibernate (`finance` and `finances_global`).

**First**, in `web.xml` I define:

1. parent context config location (`application-config.xml`)
2. servlets and their own:

   - context config locations (`dispatcherMain-servlet.xml`, `dispatcherCatalog-servlet.xml`)
   - Hibernate datasources config files (`databaseConfigMain.xml`, `databaseConfigCatalog.xml`).

**Second**, in each of servlets' config file, I create a bean `MainConfig` which reads a resource bundle - separate for each servlet (`mainServlet.properties` and `catalogServlet.properties`).

But it turns out that that configuration files are never read, so deployment failes. In log file, I have lots of `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read property "server.redis"` and `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at klab.backend.utils.MainConfig.get(MainConfig.java:351)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are my configs.

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    ...

    <!-- Configurations for the root application context (parent context) -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configurations for the DispatcherServlet application contexts (child contexts) -->

    <!-- Configurations for servlet "dispatcherMain" -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherMain</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/dispatcherMain-servlet.xml
                /WEB-INF/databaseConfigMain.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherMain</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/api/finance/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilterForFinanceMain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory1</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilterForFinanceMain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/api/finance/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Configurations for servlet "dispatcherCatalog" -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherCatalog</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/dispatcherCatalog-servlet.xml
                /WEB-INF/databaseConfigCatalog.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherCatalog</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/api/finance-global/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilterForFinanceCatalog</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilterForFinanceCatalog</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/api/finance-global/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`application-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="klab.finance.system"/>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
        <property name="validator" ref="validator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="CorsFilter" class="klab.backend.filter.CorsFilter" />

    <bean id="swagger2Config" class="klab.finance.config.SwaggerConfig"/>

</beans>
```

`dispatcherMain-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
               "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean class="klab.backend.utils.MainConfig" id="mainConfigMain">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/mainServlet.properties</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/build.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="klab.backend.controller.base.DefaultController" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="true"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.JacksonView2HttpMessageConverter">

                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.KJsonMapper">
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="true"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.JacksonView2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.KJsonMapper">
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:component-scan base-package="klab.finance.main"/>

</beans>
```

`dispatcherCatalog-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
               "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean class="klab.backend.utils.MainConfig" id="mainConfig">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/catalogServlet.properties</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/build.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="klab.backend.controller.base.DefaultController" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="true"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.JacksonView2HttpMessageConverter">

                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.KJsonMapper">
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:component-scan base-package="klab.finance.catalog"/>

</beans>
```

`databaseConfigMain.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory1" name="sessionFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>klab.finance.main.entity</value>
                <value>klab.backend.entity.finance.main</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >${jdbc.debug}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="klab.backend.utils.hibernate.RoutingDataSource">
        <property name="poolProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="max_size">3</prop>
                <prop key="min_size">1</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

`databaseConfigCatalog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>klab.backend.entity.finance.catalog</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >${jdbc.debug}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="klab.backend.utils.hibernate.RoutingDataSource">
        <property name="poolProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="max_size">3</prop>
                <prop key="min_size">1</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

`mainServlet.properties`:

```
sql.settings.limit = 1000

jdbc.debug = true

server.redis = 192.168.1.56

db.default = jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.56/finances?user=admin&password=aFdD4aEcf5j7Cia;
callback.default = http://192.168.1.57/rest/api

auto.restart=1
context.count=3

rabbit.host = 192.168.1.56
rabbit.port = 5672
rabbit.user = guest
rabbit.password = guest

monitoring.query.size = 10
monitoring.enabled = 1
application.version = ${build.number}
```

`catalogServlet.properties`:

```
sql.settings.limit = 1000

jdbc.debug = true

server.redis = 192.168.1.56

db.default = jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.56/finance_global?user=admin&password=dDeO7QcpOaDe5iqo;
callback.default = http://192.168.1.57/rest/api

auto.restart=1
context.count=3

rabbit.host = 192.168.1.56
rabbit.port = 5672
rabbit.user = guest
rabbit.password = guest

monitoring.query.size = 10
monitoring.enabled = 1
application.version = ${build.number}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the spring debug logs at start up ? Is there any error ?

Comment: @ArunM I have lots of `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read property "server.redis" ` and `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at klab.backend.utils.MainConfig.get(MainConfig.java:351)` in it.

Comment: Should not your  <init-param> be in  <context-param> ? check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931004/spring-mvc-multiple-servlets-jersey-dispatcher-problem

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma Maybe. `<context-param>` is for parent context, which is only one, or isn't? Can it be separate for each servlet?

Comment: Apologies - that is possible. I checked similar thread and you seems to be in right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865088/how-to-register-multiple-servlets-in-web-xml-in-one-spring-application