# How to define 2 servlets in 1 web.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016805/adding-multiple-servlets-in-single-web-xml), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460977/multiple-jersey-servlets-in-one-single-web-xml) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865088/how-to-register-multiple-servlets-in-web-xml-in-one-spring-application). The examples use a different framework. I'm using Atmosphere + Jersey. I want to know **how to configure 2 servlets** in a single web.xml.
**EDIT:**
web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.package1</param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <description>Admin</description>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.package2</param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Post your web.xml file content.

Comment: Did you try putting the more specific servlet+mapping (the one mapping at `/admin/*`) before the more generic?

Comment: That did the trick. I might have missed out on something the last time I tried that. Thank you @NikosParaskevopoulos

Comment: I got my mistake as well. Though here the servlet class says `org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet` I had changed it to `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`. Changed it back and worked. And also, the order does not matter.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Now that being done, resources from my `AtmosphereServlet` are not being found.

Comment: It would be great if the author Gaurav Bhor would answer himself the working solution to his question by posting a new answer below and then check it as solution.